# How transfer a Table from HBase to Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hiveql

How can I tranfer a HBase table into Hive correctly?

What I tried before can you read in this question 
[How insert overwrite table in hive with diffrent where clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346060/how-insert-overwrite-table-in-hive-with-diffrent-where-clauses)
( I made one table to import all data. The problem here is that data is still in rows and not in columns. So I made 3 tables for news, social and all with a specific where clause. After that I made 2 Joins on the tables which is giving me the result table. So I had 6 Tables at all which is not really performant!)

to sum my problem up : In HBase are column familys which are saved as rows like this.

```
count   verpassen   news    1
count   verpassen   social  0
count   verpassen   all 1
```

What I want to achieve in Hive is a datastructure like this:

```
name      news    social   all
verpassen 1       0        1
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: There is a whole page on [Hive-Hbase Integration on the Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)

Comment: You can use hbasestorage handler in hive

Comment: hbase storage Handler doesnt work for me i got this exception : FAILED: SemanticException Cannot find class 'org.apache.ha doop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the approach use can use.

use hbase storage handler to create the table in hive

example script

> CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key string, value string)  STORED BY
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH
>   SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,f1:val")
>   TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "test");

I loaded the sample data you have given into hive external table.

[image]

> select name,collect_set(concat_ws(',',type,val)) input from TESTTABLE
>   group by name ;

i am grouping the data by name.The resultant output for the above query will be
[image]

Now i wrote a custom mapper which takes the input as input parameter and emits  the values.

> **from   (select   '["all,1","social,0","news,1"]' input from TESTTABLE group by name) d  MAP d.input Using 'python test.py' as
>   all,social,news**

[image]

alternatively you can use the output to insert into another table which has column names name,all,social,news

Hope this helps

Comment: When I try to create a table i got this exception: Exception FAILED: SemanticException Cannot find class 'org.apache.ha doop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'

Comment: You have to add the hbase jars to hive lib folder.

hbase-*.jar , zookeeper*.jar, hive-hbase-handler*.jar

Comment: zookeeper.jar and hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1 is already in there. But i have alot of hbase*.jar. for example hbase-it-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar or hbase-client-0.98.0-hadoop2.jar. Which one is the right one?

Comment: I just copied all hbase *.jar from hbase to hive and rerun the example. Now i got an FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544169/what-is-the-right-way-to-set-up-hbase-hadoop-hive-to-access-hbase-through-hive