# What is the right way to set up HBase, hadoop, hive to access Hbase through hive?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hbase

I have a problem with configuring and installing hbase/hadoop/hive. What I did so far on an VM with ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS:

- installed jdk like this with the Version **jdk1.8.0_60**:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how%E2%80%8B-can-i-install-sun-o%E2%80%8Bracles-proprietary-j%E2%80%8Bava-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre%E2%80%8B

- Got **hadoop-2.6.1**  and unpacked the .tar file. after that i did some configuration:

core site.xml:

```
 <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

hadoop-env.sh

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hfu/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hfu/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

- got **hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2** and unpacked it and config it the following way:

hbase-env.sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60/

hbase-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hfu/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/hfu/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>ubuntu</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>ubuntu:16000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

- got **apache-hive-1.2.1-bin** and unpacked it :

hive-enf.sh

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hfu/hadoop-2.6.1
```

start hadoop:

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

[image]

start hbase:

```
bin/start-hbase.sh
```

[image]

In HBASE shell is creating of a table possible. I can also put some entries into it.
I also write this in console before I start hive

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true
```

to prevent an Exception

In Hive its possible to create a table and read content out of that. but as soon as I want to connect both together as described in some tutorials

[http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/05/10/hive-hbase-quickstart.html](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/05/10/hive-hbase-quickstart.html)

or http://www.n10k.com/blog/hbase-via-hive-pt1/

I get an Exception. I  also described my problem earlier in another post, but this one is much more detailed:
[How transfer a Table from HBase to Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440186/how-transfer-a-table-from-hbase-to-hive/33445056#comment54833604_33445056)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wrong versions of HBase and Hadoop. Here is an overview, which Versions from hadoop and HBase are compatibel. `http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop`